# Using spring-rabbit-test for Junit

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am trying to write a test case for rabbitMq listener. I tried using spring-rabbit-test and got the below error while running tests:

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
>   re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2018-03-06 17:10:50.113
>   ERROR 14239 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication
>   : Application run failed
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Another endpoint is already
>   registered with id 'response_queue'
>           at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.java:151)
>   ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]

I was following [https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#testing] and in the example they have shared it does not have an @Component for the listeners in ideal case that will be a component.

Now my test class also tries to get the listener resultin in the error mentioned above.

Can someone help me?

**Test configuration**

> ```
> @Configuration    
> @RabbitListenerTest
> public class RabbitMQTestConfig {
>     @Autowired
>     MyListener myListener;
> }
> ```

**Test**

> ```
> @ActiveProfiles("test")
> @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
> @SpringBootTest
> public class RabbitMQTest {
>
>     @Rule
>     public BrokerRunning brokerRunning = BrokerRunning.isRunning();
>
>     @Autowired
>     private RabbitListenerTestHarness harness;
>
>     @Test
>     public void testMyListener() {
>
>     }
> ```
>
> }

**Listener**

> ```
> @Component
> public class MyListener {
>
> @Autowired
> MyService myService;
>
>
> @RabbitListener(id = "response_queue", queues = "response")
>     public void processOrder(SomeResponse someResponse) {
>         myService.process(someResponse);
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Yeah... You will need to share your project with us. It's simple variant to let us to reproduce and play to determine the reason.

Right now I can't reproduce it with very simple Spring Boot app:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So49129095Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So49129095Application.class, args);
    }
}

@Component
public class MyListener {

    @RabbitListener(id = "response_queue", queuesToDeclare = @Queue("response"))
    public void processOrder(Object payload) {

    }

}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {So49129095Application.class, So49129095ApplicationTests.RabbitMQTestConfig.class})
public class So49129095ApplicationTests {

    @Rule
    public BrokerRunning brokerRunning = BrokerRunning.isRunning();

    @Autowired
    private RabbitListenerTestHarness harness;

    @Test
    public void testMyListener() {

    }

    @Configuration
    @RabbitListenerTest
    public static class RabbitMQTestConfig {

        @Autowired
        MyListener myListener;

    }

}
```

Seems for me I didn't miss any of your points how to configure that all together.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you register 2 listeners with same id.

Most likely you had a class with listener defined and then you manually created another bean (possibly mocked) of the same class.